# VLOOKUP with use of wildcard and CONCATENATE

Tags: excel, concatenation, wildcard, vlookup

In `F5` I have an ID. E.g `1358`. In `F6` I have a further value which I add onto the ID string. E.g `2`.

In my `'pieces'` table are a bunch of `Level ID`. E.g

`135821
135822
135823
135824`

`=VLOOKUP("*"(CONCATENATE(F5,F6))"*",pieces[[Level ID]:[Move Recorded]],2,FALSE)`.

I want to be able to find all the entries that are 13582* and list them below. I'm not sure how to do this with multiple entries and if VLOOKUP is even the best way to go. Hope I've made myself clear, any help appreciated!

Comment: Your vlookup says there are two columns of data and you want the second. but your narrative states you want the results from only the one.

Comment: Ah ok, well `[Level ID]:[Move Recorded]` actually covers columns `E:T` as I want grab data from them. How do I rephrase the formula accordingly?

Comment: Wildcard use text search as opposed to number search. In this instance you are searching for a text string but feeding in a table with number values. As far as I know there is no way to tell VLOOKUP to treat the table as text. You'll either have to add an additional column to the right of [Level ID] with something like =TEXT([Level ID],"@") or use another approach.

Comment: Further you've not specified HOW you intend on listing them below. Since the result will be dynamic in number of items returned how are you wanting to list them? In a single cell or a predefined number of rows?

Comment: Couldn't you simplify the string joining with `CONCATENATE("*",F5,F6,"*")` ?

Comment: @snoopen I'm intending on listing them in a number of rows

Answer (score 2):

Vlookup will only return the first, you need to use something like Small or Aggregate to get the list.

If you have 2010 or later than use this formula:

```
=INDEX(peices[Move Recorded],MATCH(AGGREGATE(15,6,peices[Level ID]/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*" & $F$5 & $F$6 & "*",peices[Level ID]))),ROW(1:1)),peices[Level ID],0))
```

If you have 2007 or earlier than you will need to use this array formula:

```
=INDEX(peices[Move Recorded],MATCH(SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*" & $F$5 &$F$6& "*",peices[Level ID])),peices[Level ID]),ROW(1:1)),peices[Level ID],0))
```

Being an array it will need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Using 2010.
`=INDEX(pieces[Tenant Type],MATCH(AGGREGATE(15,6,pieces[Level ID]/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F5 & F6 & "*",pieces[Level ID]))),ROW(1:1)),pieces[Level ID],0))`

Returns with #N/A. 
Doubt I've got it right. What do the function number and options mean?

Comment: 15 is SMALL() and 6 ignores errors.  A couple of Questions; Are you sure that there is a level ID for the values in F5 and F6? Second this depends on Level Ids being numbers and not text.  Also I missed that you wanted a wild card in front, see edit and try that.

Comment: You might also want to wrap this in IFERROR and return an empty string when no result is found. Or in the case that IFERROR is not available, move the formula to a different location and use regular IF to reference the calculated values.

Comment: @snoopen I would wait till we find why it is not working at the moment.  But I agree once the formula is working wrap it in IFERROR(*formula*,"")

Comment: @ScottCraner I failed to mention that LevelID `1358` in F5 and the `2` in F6 are on a different page, where the formula is located.

Or in other words the table 'pieces' is in a page named 'pieces' whilst F5 and F6 are on a page named 'front'.

Comment: @Berry A different sheet than what?  The table or the output list or both?

Comment: @ScottCraner The table

Comment: ROW(Pieces!1:1)) Doesn't fix it either :(

Comment: That should not matter, the table is like a workbook named range.  If the output list is on the same page it should work.  I just noticed you do not have F5 and F6 as absolute references,  they need to be $F$5 and $F$6.  See the latest edit and use that formula.  If F5 and F6 are on a different sheet than the output list then put: '*YourSheetName*'!$F$5.  The ROW(1:1), does not get changed it will change on its own as you drag the formula down.  Please see the latest edit and use that formula, as is. @Berry

Comment: I use a slight variation without issue in a few worksheets which in your case would be:
`=INDEX(pieces[Tenant Type],AGGREGATE(15,6,SEARCH("*"&$F$5&$H$5&"*",pieces[Level ID])*ROW(pieces[Level ID]),ROW(1:1))-ROW(pieces[Level ID])+1)`

Comment: @ScottCraner I tried the first formula you provided however I added a three digit number and 135832 to Level ID and indeed got unexpected results. An Error with the three digit number and incorrect results with 135832 added.

Comment: @snoopen Ok cool, This is picking up the tenant type! However if I keep dragging down it keeps picking them up, implying that it's finding entries despite there only being four with suitable ID's (135821,135822,135823,135824).

Comment: Well two things first do you have any other numbers that might be incorrectly matching like "213582"? Second I should have included an IFERROR wrapper `=IFERROR(INDEX(pieces[Tenant Type],AGGREGATE(15,6,SEARCH("*"&$F$5&$H$5&"*",pieces[Level ID])*ROW(pieces[Level ID]),ROW(1:1))-ROW(pieces[Level ID])+1),"")`

Comment: You can have a play around with the result vector to see which values are returning positive. For example this will list all the rows being matched `=IFERROR(ROW(pieces[Level ID]),AGGREGATE(15,6,SEARCH("*"&$F$5&$H$5&"*",pieces[Level ID])*ROW(pieces[Level ID]),ROW(1:1))-ROW(pieces[Level ID])+1),"")`

Comment: Also don't forget to change F5 and H5 to your parameters locations.